# In photoelectric effect, the plates have neutral charge?

Tags: photoelectric-effect

Consider the basic schematic for photoelectric effect without battery

Initially, light falls on a plate charging it positively (because it ejects electrons) and those electrons reach the other plate charging it negatively, but since they are connected to each other, the excess of electrons in one is compensated by the plate that lacks electrons to the Light speed, am I correct?
[image]

Answer (score 1):

When the electron is ejected from a plate, due to fact that it’s connected by a wire to the other plate, there’s already a reservoir of free electrons accessible to it. So as soon as an electron is ejected, an electron from the wire replaces it and so on until the other plate is now positively charged and gets neutralised by the photoelectron.

The speed of this transfer is decided by the conductivity of the system.

Answer (score 0):

Actually in your picture of photoelectric effect there must be a battery or cell which will provide an electric field which will give the photoelectrons a direction towards the positive plate. These photoelectrons then reach the negative end (as you said) but in this process the battery has to do some work and thus it's energy goes on decreasing and   a time comes when the battery loses all of its energy and hence their will be no source of electric field and thus the photoelectric effect stops.

Also you can't predict photoelectric effect in your case because their would not be any electric current to notice because without the electric field associated with the wire , charges would be moving randomly and their net effect will be zero. So you can't say whether the effect took place and to associate the wires and the plates with electric field at the same time, you need a battery for sure.

Hope it helps.

Comment: what happens if I put an external E field?

Comment: If you don't use a battery then both the plates will be neutral and by external electric field the electrons will reach the other plate but due to this the other plate will be negatively charged creating its own electric field in the opposite direction and it will oppose the photoelectrons to reach that plate.

Answer (score 0):

A small fraction of the photons striking the illuminated plate will cause electrons to be ejected out through the surface of that plate.  A fraction of those will strike the other plate causing an almost immediate flow of current through the connecting wire, which tends to keep both plates nearly neutral.  (The actual drift velocity of the electrons in the wire will be quite low.) If the plates are not connected, electrons will build up on the collecting plate. The resulting electric field will push those of lower energy back to the illuminated plate.  If the incoming light is monochromatic, the maximum voltage difference will be determined by the frequency of the incoming photons.